# FIMSynchronization error - 6801

Tags: user-profile-service, ups, fim

I have just taken over an environment. I am not too familiar with SP and am temporarily managing the farm. Every night there are errors from `FIMSynchronizationService`. Example one below.

In the UPS I see that 90% of our users are correct with the xyz\accountname as we use this as our login, but all new synced users are AD\accountname. Looking for some guidance here.

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileException: Exception while trying to migrate account 'xyz\test' to 'AD\test'. ---> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The user does not exist or is not unique. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The user does not exist or is not unique.0x81020054
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.SelectSitesAndUserInfoForMigration(Object& pvarContentDsns, Object& pvarContentIds, String bstrOldLogin, String bstrNewLogin, String bstrFullUserKey, Boolean bEnforceSidHistory, Guid guidSubscriptionId, String& pbstrNewLogin, Byte[]& ppsaOldSid, Byte[]& ppsaNewSid, Object& pvarSidHistory, Object& pvarSiteIds)
>      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.SelectSitesAndUserInfoForMigration(Object& pvarContentDsns, Object& pvarContentIds, String bstrOldLogin, String bstrNewLogin, String bstrFullUserKey, Boolean bEnforceSidHistory, Guid guidSubscriptionId, String& pbstrNewLogin, Byte[]& ppsaOldSid, Byte[]& ppsaNewSid, Object& pvarSidHistory, Object& pvarSiteIds)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Comment: Are you performing a domain migration? Is it possible these two accounts have a matching SID or one has a SID with the other matching that value in the sidHistory attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the NetBIOS Domain Name differs from the Full Qualified Domain Name. This requires some configuration in UserProfileService:

- Note all Settings inside your current Sync connection
- Delete the existing faulty Synchronization Connection in the User Profile Service Application.
- Open the SharePoint 2013 Management Shell with administrative rights.
- Run Get-SPServiceApplication and copy the GUID of the User Profile Service Application.
- Run this script in with the correct GUID.

  $UserProfile = Get-SPServiceApplication -Id *GUID*
  $UserProfile.NetBIOSDomainNamesEnabled=1
  $UserProfile.Update()
- Create a new Synchronization Connection with Active Directory Domain Services.
- Run a full “Start Profile Synchronization”.

Some References:
 [Enable NetBIOS Name for User Profile Service Application in SharePoint](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/02/enable-netbios-name-for-user-profile-service-application.html)
[Rational Guide to implementing SharePoint Server 2010 User Profile Synchronization](http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx)

Comment: Will this have any effect on the current mysites or profiles that are correct there at xyz\username?

Comment: Is "XYZ" NetBIOS Domain Name or FQDN?

Comment: XYZ is the netbios name

Comment: This *should* not affect existing xyz-users as UPS will recognize them again with their NetBIOS-Domain. If you rely on those profiles and their MySites, i suggest you to implement this in a testing-environment first. Also be aware that MySites get deleted 30 days after UPS does no longer recognize the Profile. https://platinumdogs.me/2012/10/18/sharepoint-demystifying-user-profile-deletion-mysite-removal/